# Vue.js update ajax data in data property variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I am new in Vue.js. I want to update data from ajax data.

```
<template>
  <span class="label_cont">This is to certify that</span> {{ name }}
</template>
```

I want to `{{ name }}` variable from ajax data. 
Here is my js code

```
export default{
  created(){
    const url = 'app/result.php';
    this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
      this.resp = response.body;
    });
  },
  data(){  
    return {
     resp:[],
     name: resp.name,
   }
  }
}
```

In my ajax `name` property is in `this.resp.name`

**Update:**

Here is my ajax response data format

```
{
  "name": "X",
  "class": "Y",
  "roll": "Z"
}
```

Comment: what data you have response.body? show us data format

Comment: I have update the data format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the extra line to your callback below.

```
this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
  this.resp = response.body;
  this.name = response.name
});
```

In your data just initialize it to null.

```
data(){  
  return {
    resp:[],
    name: null,
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could just use

```
{{resp.name}}
```

in your template.